# sql, how to eliminated repeated data across columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table like this

```
customer1    customer2    city
A                B          NY
B                A          NY
A                C          NY
A                D          NY
D                A          NY
C                A          NY
```

I am just interested in unique combination .

A B  or B A   etc

**Output I need is**

```
customer1    customer2    city
A                B          NY
A                C          NY
A                D          NY
```

Comment: if the key columns are comparable, and if their number is small then you can create a composite column of their sorted-concatenated values and select distincts on that temp table. If you use this approach, be sure to use something uncommon to glue the keys in the composite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to translate this to Oracle (if it is possible at all), but Postgres gives the short, if perhaps inefficient,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (LEAST(c1, c2), GREATEST(c1, c2))
   LEAST(c1, c2), GREATEST(c1, c2), city FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you need.  The 2 case statements will sort the two columns.  Once sorted, you can just get the distinct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN customer1 < customer2 THEN customer1 ELSE customer2 END customer1,
CASE WHEN customer1 > customer2 THEN customer1 ELSE customer2 END customer2,
city
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This should be more efficient than mine, though you lose who was originally customer 1/2

Answer (score 1):

We can get half way there by requiring customer1 <= customer2, but this is too restrictive. We need to add back in the cases where custerm1 > customer2, but not in first set.  The NOT IN operator will work for us here, as long as we tweak the column names.

```
  SELECT c1, c2, city
  FROM t
  HAVING c1 <= c2
UNION
  SELECT c1, c2, city
  FROM t
  WHERE c1 > c2
  AND (c1, c2, city) NOT IN
  (
    SELECT c2 AS c1
         , c1 AS c2
         , city
    FROM t
    WHERE c1 <= c2
  )
```

See it in action here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78d1c/23

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(customer1, customer2),
                GREATEST(customer1, customer2),
                city
FROM T
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b73ba/1
Simple and easy to understand. But not be very efficient (can't use your index).

---

If you need to keep `customer1` and `customer2` in the same order as in the original table for non-duplicates, you probably need something more complex:

```
SELECT T.* FROM T
JOIN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) RID
      FROM T GROUP BY LEAST(customer1, customer2),
                GREATEST(customer1, customer2),
                city) V
ON T.ROWID = V.RID
```

Or (maybe better):

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T T1
LEFT JOIN T T2 
ON T1.city = T2.city 
AND T1.customer1 = T2.customer2
AND T1.customer2 = T2.customer1
WHERE T2.city IS NULL OR T1.customer1 < T1.customer2
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f7bbd/3 for a comparison of those three solutions.